# How to create a database from an XML file's DTD

Tags: xml

I have a fairly large and complex self-describing XML file (It's an Apple Healthkit export; 183 MB).

Are there any utilities available to create a database in MySQL or PostgreSQL  with the tables and fields described in the XML file's DTD?

(If not, I suppose PHP's SimpleXML Parser would help but would require more thought.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HealthData [
<!-- HealthKit Export Version: 3 -->
<!ELEMENT HealthData (ExportDate,Me,(Record|Correlation|Workout|ActivitySummary)*)>
<!ATTLIST HealthData
  locale CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT ExportDate EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST ExportDate
  value CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT Me EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST Me
  HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth         CDATA #REQUIRED
  HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex       CDATA #REQUIRED
  HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType           CDATA #REQUIRED
  HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierFitzpatrickSkinType CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT Record (MetadataEntry*)>
<!ATTLIST Record
  type          CDATA #REQUIRED
  unit          CDATA #IMPLIED
  value         CDATA #IMPLIED
  sourceName    CDATA #REQUIRED
  sourceVersion CDATA #IMPLIED
  device        CDATA #IMPLIED
  creationDate  CDATA #IMPLIED
  startDate     CDATA #REQUIRED
  endDate       CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!-- Note: Any Records that appear as children of a correlation also appear as top-level records in this document. -->
<!ELEMENT Correlation ((MetadataEntry|Record)*)>
<!ATTLIST Correlation
  type          CDATA #REQUIRED
  sourceName    CDATA #REQUIRED
  sourceVersion CDATA #IMPLIED
  device        CDATA #IMPLIED
  creationDate  CDATA #IMPLIED
  startDate     CDATA #REQUIRED
  endDate       CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT Workout ((MetadataEntry|WorkoutEvent)*)>
<!ATTLIST Workout
  workoutActivityType   CDATA #REQUIRED
  duration              CDATA #IMPLIED
  durationUnit          CDATA #IMPLIED
  totalDistance         CDATA #IMPLIED
  totalDistanceUnit     CDATA #IMPLIED
  totalEnergyBurned     CDATA #IMPLIED
  totalEnergyBurnedUnit CDATA #IMPLIED
  sourceName            CDATA #REQUIRED
  sourceVersion         CDATA #IMPLIED
  device                CDATA #IMPLIED
  creationDate          CDATA #IMPLIED
  startDate             CDATA #REQUIRED
  endDate               CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT WorkoutEvent EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST WorkoutEvent
  type CDATA #REQUIRED
  date CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT ActivitySummary EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST ActivitySummary
  dateComponents           CDATA #IMPLIED
  activeEnergyBurned       CDATA #IMPLIED
  activeEnergyBurnedGoal   CDATA #IMPLIED
  activeEnergyBurnedUnit   CDATA #IMPLIED
  appleExerciseTime        CDATA #IMPLIED
  appleExerciseTimeGoal    CDATA #IMPLIED
  appleStandHours          CDATA #IMPLIED
  appleStandHoursGoal      CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT MetadataEntry EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST MetadataEntry
  key   CDATA #REQUIRED
  value CDATA #REQUIRED
>
]>
<HealthData locale="en_GB"> ... etc. (data)
```

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941353/xml-dtd-sql-schema

Answer (score 2):

Use the following tools:

> 1) create full sql schema from DTD.

- [DTDParse](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SGML-DTDParse/bin/dtdparse) + [XML::RDB](http://search.cpan.org/~metzzo/XML-RDB/RDB.pm)

> 2) convert XML doc with data into SQL.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121456/transform-xml-using-xslt-to-sql

**References**

- <strike>[DTD Tools](http://www.xmlpitstop.com/ListTools/DispContentType/DTD/PageNumber/1.aspx)</strike> (the link no longer works)
- [XML Matters: Using Python modules xml2sql and dtd2sql](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-matters12.html)